# Unable to set default browser in Windows 10 - "No installed app for this file or protocol"

Tags: google-chrome, windows-10

My wife's Windows 10 computer is having an issue where other programs are unable to open web sites because no application could be found to handle "http" or "https". She has both IE and Chrome installed on the machine, and both seem to work fine when opened from the start menu.

Trying to set the default web browser to Chrome from Chrome itself causes Windows to open the "Look for this app in the app store" prompt. Clicking on the app store link only shows four applications - only one of which is actually a browser called "Sidekick Private Browser". I'm loathe to install something like that since there are already two good working browsers on the machine.

Going into the Windows system settings and setting the default browser from Default Apps results in more or less the same thing - I click on "Choose a default" under the Web browser option and a modal comes up titled "Choose an app". The error message says "There is no installed app for this type of file or protocol" followed by a link to the app store.

My hunch is that there's either something corrupted in the registry that makes it so that http and https requests are mishandled since, in the very least, IE should come up as a default browser. However, I have no idea what that problem may be. I ran sfc /scannow, but no errors came up.

Any ideas? Thank you in advance!

Comment: The first list is just suggestions.  There is a way to expand that list to the applications you actually have installed, expand the list, then select the browser you wish to use.

Comment: Not sure that addresses the issue, though. In the app store, I see no option to expand the list. The core of the issue is that I have at least two apps that can handle http and https installed, but Windows seems to not be recognizing that. I assume this is some registry thing I'm missing?

Comment: Chrome nor Edge is a Windows Store application, so why are you going to the app store?

Comment: It's making me go to the app store to find an appropriate app to set for that default. It's not recognizing the IE or Chrome that was already installed on the machine as being able to handle those requests.

Answer (score 2):

Being fairly confident this is an issue with the registry, I decided to try reinstalling Chrome. Sure enough, doing so made it show up in the list of possible applications to set for the default web browser. Curious that IE still isn't listed there, but something must have blown away the registry entries that identify Chrome and IE as being capable of handling http and https requests. Also curious that passing that on to the Microsoft app store did not show ANY of the major browsers as possible contenders to handle this. In short, I think the registry is borked somehow and I still have no idea how to fix that. But, in the mean time, it looks like I'm at least able to set Chrome as a default. If this changes, I'll update again here.